# Save Button not work on jQuery-UI Connected Sortable Lists

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-ui

According to Test Drag&Drop element with connectedSortable from sortable1 at left side and sortable2 at right side By Save Button we still have problem that the result aray data not sent to save to my database.

**HTML file**

```
<div style="margin: 25px 0;">
  <button id="save">Save</button>
</div>

<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable"><b>Left side</b>
  <!--<?php echo $column1; ?>-->
  <li id="entry_1" class="ui-state-default">Entry #1</li>
  <li id="entry_2" class="ui-state-default">Entry #2</li>
  <li id="entry_3" class="ui-state-default">Entry #3</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable"><b>Right side</b>
  <!--<?php echo $column2; ?>-->
  <li id="entry_4" class="ui-state-default">Entry #4</li>
  <li id="entry_5" class="ui-state-default">Entry #5</li>
  <li id="entry_6" class="ui-state-default">Entry #6</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: '.connectedSortable',

        update: function (event, ui) {
            var order = $(this).sortable('serialize');

            $(document).on("click", "#save", function () 
            { 
                $.ajax(
                {
                    //data: order,
                    //data: $("#sortable").sortable("serialize"),
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'draggable.php',
                    data: 
                    {
                        sort1:$("#sortable1").sortable('serialize'),
                        sort2:$("#sortable2").sortable('serialize')
                    },
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                        //$('.success').fadeIn(500);
                    }
                });
            });
        }


    }).disableSelection();
    $('#save').on('click', function () {
        var r = $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable("toArray");
        var a = $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable("serialize", {
            attribute: "id"
        });
        console.log(r, a);
    });
});
```

Data should be save into database after click save button.

But my current demo on this page we have problem.

We can drag&drop but the data not save to database.
some thing may be misssing in javascript function save or ajax update.

Remark : About project auto save no have problem for me we have problem only save by save button you can see here jsfiddle.net/verawat/7cu6vtqf/3

I tried to add Demo example on jsfiddle as below.

[1. Drag&Drop Connected Sortable Auto Save **(Good job. No have Problem)**](https://jsfiddle.net/verawat/7cu6vtqf/11/)

[2. Drag&Drop Connected Sortable Save by onClick Button Save **(This is my problem)**](https://jsfiddle.net/verawat/tu13qzfm/16/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First time an update happens, you're not sending any AJAX request, only adding an event handler.

You shouldn't add event handlers in other event handlers. Your code should be something like:

```js
$(function() {
  function sendRequest() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'draggable.php',
      data: {
        sort1: $("#sortable1").sortable('serialize'),
        sort2: $("#sortable2").sortable('serialize')
      },
      success: function(html) {
        //$('.success').fadeIn(500);
      }
    });
  }

  $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
    connectWith: '.connectedSortable',
    update: sendRequest
  });

  $(document).on("click", "#save", sendRequest)
});
```

Comment: Thank TJ for your kindly to help me.
Your code is auto save after drag element.
thank but still not close my problem.

We need only click on save button then to save data to database.

Comment: You don't want auto save? then just remove `update: sendRequest`?

Comment: Thank TJ . I tried to remove `update: sendRequest` per your comment. the result is OK (Not auto save after drag element) but the major problem still occurred (Save Button not work , can not save when I click button save), 

We need only click on save button then to save data to database. Thank TJ for continue help. I love you.

Comment: @VerawatKrawnneat that's because you're using ancient version of jQuery . Use newer version above `1.7` https://jsfiddle.net/tu13qzfm/17/ or use old syntax for event binding.

Comment: Thank Mr. Tj.  --- Work already... Successfully very thankful for the advice. This project is very important to me. My family and I will never forget you for this.